# Grails 4 and Views-Json 2 : Build fails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade a Grails app from 3.3 to 4 (specifically 4.0.3 for now) and the Views-Json 2.0.2 plugin. Profile is angular.

When I run the app in development mode everything works.  However when I attempt to build using `gradlew :server-api:assemble` the build fails at the Task :server-api:compileGsonViews  (yeah, renamed 'server' to 'server-api' for clarity).

It looks like it's not finding my Java classes (there are a few under `src/main/java`).

I've see refs to setting the classpath for the compileGsonViews, but I was undable to make it work.

Anyone with suggestions?

Running on Windows 10 with latest OpenJDK 1.8.x

Comment: I thought I had resolved the issue by fixing an integration test compilation problem; however poking around a bit more I found this was not the case.  I had commented out the build plugin for the grails views and when that was run via command-line compilation does work - I assume this means any GSON views will be dynamic, I'll try a test deployment when I can.  I'd had an issue in that I'd used IntelliJ "smart run" of the command before and I think that was for some reason not respecting commenting out the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I seem to have stumbled on the solution.  In my build.gradle I had enabled the grails pathingJar, commenting that out allowed my war to build.  However with the property commented out, I was unable to use the `gradlew bootRun` command as it failed due to the path being too long.

The solution (for me) was to add a build property, the build file then looks like:

```
def usePathing = Boolean.valueOf( System.getProperty('pathingJar', 'false') )
if (usePathing) {
  grails {
    pathingJar = true
  }
}
```

If I was better with gradle I think I could (maybe) determine the goal that is being targeted and use that, but the above works.  The commend to assemble the war is the same; but to run the app directly I need to make it  `gradlew server-api:bootRun -DpathingJar=true`